# opening jquery modal on pageload

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup, modal-dialog, pageload

I have a function that opens a modal window on button click.
How do I modify this so that it opens on page load (well... after a form is processed)

here is the function that opens the dialog:

```
$j(function () {
    $j('#popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({ 
        openButton: '#clicker', 
        closeButton: '#close-btn' 
    });
});
```

here is where it needs to go:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('form').submit(function(){
 $('#popup-wrapper').trigger('click');
});
```

### update

you have to submit the form via ajax(post) and call above function in `complete:` or `success:` section

alternative:(not tested)

```
<?php if($formproc->ProcessForm()) { ?>
       <script>$('#popup-wrapper').trigger('click');</script>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: then you have to submit form via ajax. which page you want to open.

Comment: i want the popup to appear instead of the page redirecting

Answer (score 0):

I may well have this wrong, but if you're looking to open this up on your "thank-you.php" page, upon page load (as I see the question) you could just put the following anywhere in your html (preferably in the head after the jquery include)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $j('#popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({ openButton: '#clicker', closeButton: '#close-btn' });
    });
</script>
```

Apologies if I've completely misunderstood this one though...

good luck!

**EDIT**

Okay, if you want it instead, why not capture the  string in a php variable, for later use down your page? like...

```
$modal = '';

if ($userHasPosted){

    $modal = "<script ... />";

}

... later in the page (maybe in the head somewhere) ...

echo $modal;
```

Does that make any sense at all?

Comment: sorry if i have explained this badly...
I want the dialog to popup INSTEAD of the page- re-direct.

Comment: I think at this point it would be beneficial if you could provide entire code sources for this. Might be quicker than people trying to infer code.